# didRegisterForRemoteNotificatiornsWithDeviceToken doesn't fire

Tags: apple-push-notifications

So I got didRegisterForRemoteNotificatiornsWithDeviceToken to fire a couple of times while I was debugging and testing... Now it doesn't wanna fire at all... Is there a restriction? Else what can it be?

Comment: is that the provisioning profile is enabled for the push?

Comment: Yes the event did fire many times before but after a couple of times it is now for some weird reason not firing...

Answer (score 0):

Very weird one... Am running iPad 3 with iOS 6.0.1, if I re-install the provisioning profile and the application it all works fine.